# Python Pandas: cannot do slice indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to work with a pandas multiindex dataframe that looks like this:

```
                   end ref|alt
chrom start
chr1  3000714  3000715     T|G
      3001065  3001066     G|T
      3001110  3001111     G|C
      3001131  3001132     G|A
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
df.loc[('chr1', slice(3000714, 3001110))]
```

That fails with the following error:

> cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [1204741] of

`df.index.levels[1].dtype` returns `dtype('int64')`, so it *should* work with integer slices right?

Also, any comments on how to do this *efficiently* would be valuable, as the dataframe has 12 million rows and I need to query it with this kind of slice query ~70 million times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need add `,:` to the end - it means you need slicing rows, but need all columns:

```
print (df.loc[('chr1', slice(3000714, 3001110)),:])
                   end ref|alt
chrom start                   
chr1  3000714  3000715     T|G
      3001065  3001066     G|T
      3001110  3001111     G|C
```

Another solution is add `axis=0` to [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc(axis=0)[('chr1', slice(3000714, 3001110))])
                   end ref|alt
chrom start                   
chr1  3000714  3000715     T|G
      3001065  3001066     G|T
      3001110  3001111     G|C
```

But if need only `3000714` and `3001110`:

```
print (df.loc[('chr1', [3000714, 3001110]),:])
                   end ref|alt
chrom start                   
chr1  3000714  3000715     T|G
      3001110  3001111     G|C

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['chr1', [3000714, 3001110]],:])
                   end ref|alt
chrom start                   
chr1  3000714  3000715     T|G
      3001110  3001111     G|C
```

**Timings**:

```
In [21]: %timeit (df.loc[('chr1', slice(3000714, 3001110)),:])
1000 loops, best of 3: 757 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit (df.loc(axis=0)[('chr1', slice(3000714, 3001110))])
1000 loops, best of 3: 743 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit (df.loc[('chr1', [3000714, 3001110]),:])
1000 loops, best of 3: 824 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit (df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['chr1', [3000714, 3001110]],:])
The slowest run took 5.35 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 826 µs per loop
```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked perfectly. Thanks for the great explanation. I also realized that for my case here, because my first level index was so much smaller than the second (there were 23 items in the `level[0]` index and 12.6 million in the `level[1]` index), I got a greater speed up by splitting the dataframe into a dictionary on the first index. On my full dataframe, the `df.loc(axis=0)[('chr1', slice(3000714, 3001110))]` method took 218 ms per loop, whereas making the dictionary and doing `dfs['chr1'].loc[3000714:3001110]` took only 95.7 µs per loop. Thanks again!

Comment: @jezrael, how would i select a dataframe from one index to another..in  that range..i have function that users.index=np.arange(0,len(users))  this is returning nothing...users.loc[start:end:] empty dataframe,but users.dataframe has content